# How to find intersection of two arrays (Optimal solution)

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I am writting algorithm for intersection of two arrays A and B , I want an optimized solution in terms of space complexity and time complexity.
I have written algorithm and it works fine but i want to know if there is any more optimal solution then this exist or if someone could provide me.

What i do is:

(1) Find the Smallest size array among two.

(2) The new array wil be of size allocated size equal to smaller size array

(3) From smaller size array i go and compare with each element in bigger array if it exists one ,i get it in third array"C" and break it right there (because we need to find intersection, even if it repeats 100 times after
    we don't care for us only one existence is enough to put in third array). At the same time we also have to check if the element in smaller array which to be compared with all elements in bigger array already exist in third array, Example `A=[0,1,1], B[0,1,2,3]`.
 Now we start with A's first element, it is present in array B we save it in `C[0]`, then go to second , now C is `[0,1]`, and  in next step we again have 1 to compare, which we have already compared.So for this situation we have to do check if element to be compare already exist in array C then we eliminate check for it.

(4) We store the found element in C (third array) and print it.

My full working code for it is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] aar1 = { 0, 1, 1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 9, 11, 2, 2,3,3,3,3,3,1 };
            int[] aar2 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
            int[] arr3 = findIntersection(aar1, aar2);
            Console.WriteLine("the array is : " + arr3);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static int[] findIntersection(int[] aar1, int[] aar2)
        {
            int[] arr3 = { 0 };
            if (aar1.Count() < aar2.Count())
            {
                int counter = 0;
                arr3 = new int[aar1.Count()];
                foreach (int var1 in aar1)
                {
                    if (!checkifInThirdArray(var1, arr3))
                    {
                        foreach (int var2 in aar2)
                        {
                            if (var1 == var2)
                            {
                                arr3[counter++] = var1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                int counter = 0;
                arr3 = new int[aar1.Count()];
                foreach (int var2 in aar2)
                {
                    if (!checkifInThirdArray(var2, arr3))
                    {
                        foreach (int var1 in aar1)
                        {
                            if (var2 == var1)
                            {
                                arr3[counter++] = var2;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return arr3;
        }

        private static bool checkifInThirdArray(int var1, int[] arr3)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            if (arr3 != null)
            {
                foreach (int arr in arr3)
                {
                    if (arr == var1) { flag = true; break; }
                }
            }
            return flag;
        }
    }
}
```

One space complexity issue i found is (the others i would really appreciate if you let me know with solution if you find any) :

(1) When i allocate the size to third array, i allocate the Min of the two arrays to be compared, In case if the intersection element are too less then we 
 have unnecessarily allocated the extra memory. How to solve this issue ?

**Please note that i don't have to use any inbuilt function like intersection() or any other.**

Comment: Use linq Intersect which uses hashset. You can see its implementation and write your own.

Comment: How it will improve as compared to the current solution. Please explain in detail by writting below as answer, so that i can even mark you if you are useful to me.

Comment: @struggling It will not improve this algorithm. However, it won't worsen it. So, why not to use a one-line ready solution instead of reinventing the wheel and implementing your own.

Comment: @struggling HashSet is optimized collection. It has time complexity of `O(1)` for accessing , adding and removing items. means it doesnt really matter how big your collection is, the performance is almost same. Also Hashset does not contain duplicate items. because it uses hashkeys to access its elements. therefore it can not contain duplicate key and each key must be unique. Intersect uses this hashset to perform intersection. the time complexity is `O(m+n)`.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary , I also know that it has complexity O(1) and its optimal. But could you please give me algorithm (by ansering below) ? It would be really helpful

Comment: This seems like a homework isnt it? i appreciate that you tried to do this your self. i know the way using hashset but that still requires built-in functions like `Add`,`Remove` of the `HashSet`  class. so i dont think i would really help you. but let me know what you think.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Actually this is not my home work. I just tried to learn. Ok, if using hashset we are obliged to use inbuilt function so it's not good for me because i am writing algo to learn. But i would really appreciate if you could please let me know any solution for avoiding extra memory allocation of third array issue( which i discussed at bottom at point (1)) ? Could you please do it ?

Comment: You have to fist run an algorithm that determines the size of result array!!! thats right the algorithm should search for items and actually do something like intersect. then another algorithm will create the array with exact size and will do intersect again! but it will fill the array this time. As you can see this is not efficient. in fact you should not worry about very little amount memory consumption. if you are working with large Sets then i suggest you use `List` type that has dynamic length. it uses array internally but its fast. or use `LinkedList`. it does not have array. but slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your solution is an `O(n2)` one in that, for every single element in one array, you may need to process every single element in the other (in the case where the intersection is the null set). You should be aware that C# actually *has* facilities for finding the intersection of arrays but, should you wish to implement your own, read on.

You would probably be better of sorting both arrays (in-place if allowed otherwise to a separate collection) then doing a merge-check of the two to construct another. The sort could be `O(n log n)` and the merge check would be `O(n)`.

If you're wondering what I mean by merge check, it's simply processing both (sorted) arrays side by side.

If the first element in both matches, you have an intersect point and you should store that value and advance both lists until the next value is different.

If they're different, there's no intersect point and you can advance the array with the lowest value until it changes.

---

By way of example, here's some code in Python (the *ideal* pseudo-code language) that implements such a solution. Array `a` contains all the multiples of three between 0 and 18 inclusive (in arbitrary order and including duplicates), while array `b` has all the even numbers in that range (again, with some duplicates and ordered "randomly").

```
a = [0,3,15,3,9,6,12,15,18,6]
b = [10,0,2,12,4,6,18,8,16,10,12,6,14,16]

# Copy and sort.

a2 = a; a2.sort()
b2 = b; b2.sort()

# Initial pointers and results for merge check.

ap = 0
bp = 0
c = []

# Continue until either array is exhausted.

while ap < len(a2) and bp < len(b2):
    # Check for intersect or which list has lowest value.

    if a2[ap] == b2[bp]:
        # Intersect, save, advance both lists to next number.

        val = a2[ap]
        c.append(val)
        while ap < len(a2) and a2[ap] == val:
            ap += 1
        while bp < len(b2) and b2[bp] == val:
            bp += 1
    elif a2[ap] < b2[bp]:
        # A has smallest, advance it to next number.

        val = a2[ap]
        while ap < len(a2) and a2[ap] == val:
            ap += 1
    else:
        # B has smallest, advance it to next number.

        val = b2[bp]
        while bp < len(b2) and b2[bp] == val:
            bp += 1

print(c)
```

If you run that, you'll see the intersect list that's formed between the two arrays:

```
[0, 6, 12, 18]
```

Comment: @padiablo, Wow that's the good idea, but still it has a complexity, thanks if you could provide the solution for it. The problem is when you will allocate the third array, you have to provide it the size, and if you even provide it thesize equal to minimum of the two arrays A and B, then also some time most of the memory is allocated unncessarily. Do you have solution for it also ?

Comment: And there is one more issue , what if i have lets say A=[0,1,1,2,5,7] and B=[0,1,2,5]  after sorting? Now during the third check the algo will fail.

Comment: @struggling, duplicates won't cause a problem, assuming you "advance the array with the lowest value until it changes" as stated. I've added some sample code as proof of concept.

Comment: your solution is perfect one, just only one question in my implementation is un-answered (the one which i have pointed (1) at the end of asked question), I mean about extra memory allocation created in third array (because we find the minimum size array among the two and we allocate third with same size, the case would be the same in your implementation as well). After this answer i will mark you as answer as all my dounts and questions are clear :) Thanks

Comment: @struggling, yes, there is potential wastage there since the final intersect array may be larger than required. However, without making two passes or dynamically expanding the array as things are added, it's still the best approach. You know `min(sz(a),sz(b))` will be the maximum size needed for the intersect so just allocate that. If it turns out to be too big, you can shrink it when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not understanding you right but why don't you use the following;

```
int[] aar1 = { 0, 1, 1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 9, 11, 2, 2,3,3,3,3,3,1 };
int[] aar2 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

aarResult = aar1.Intersect(aar2).ToArray();
```

This will result in an array with only the space needed and intersects the arrays. You can also initialize the aarResult as follows to get the minimum array size:

```
int[] aarResult = new int[Math.Min(aar1.Count(), aar2.Count())];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ `Intersect` method. It uses hashing and works for linear `O(N+M)` which is faster than your algorithm:

```
int[] aar1 = { 0, 1, 1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 9, 11, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1 };
int[] aar2 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

int[] result = aar1.Intersect(aar2).ToArray();
```

It will also solve your unnecessarily allocated items problem, because it will create an array of the exact answer size.